# Antiseize in plumbing? Alternate screw heads and materials for screws securing washers?

Tags: plumbing, fastener

My house was made in 1965. Water is somewhat hard. Sometimes a faucet fixture leaks. When I take it apart the solution is often to replace a washer secured with a #8 pan head screw. [Sometimes the screw is seized and the head strips](https://twitter.com/zippy1981/status/1032056938803150849). Its cheaper and easier to replace the screw than the whole part, especially for older fixtures. My instinct is that using anti-seize and/or a different screw head would mean in a decade or two  when I replace the washers again I will have an easier time. So my questions:

- Is regular anti-seize ok for drinking water? Do I need to get the food safe kind? Will it actually last?
- When constantly exposed to hard municipal water, can I use stainless steel or silicon bronze screws in the brass or wil lgalvinic corrosion be a problem? My assumption is that its harder to strip a harder fastener.
- will socket cap or hex screws fit in these fixtures or is my only choice torx/hex/robertson pan head screws if I want a fastner less prone to stripping?

Answer (score 1):

Stainless will be stronger than brass , so less likely to strip. Assuming a brass stem , galvanic corrosion should not be a problem. The stainless is unlikely to gall with the brass shaft. A wrap of teflon tape/dope will help prevent sticking. I have found plain screw driver slot or Philips to be good enough but a stronger head is good if you can find it.

Comment: tape in a small #8 screw is going to be hard, but dope is a good idea.